# Issue with slicer Filtering from different data sets/ columns

Tags: pivot-table, powerpoint, data-manipulation, data-modeling, slicers

I am having a problem trying to understand how to accomplish this. I want to use one set of slicers in my Excel spreadsheet to drill down to specific information. The problem is that I have duplicated Model names under the "Intel" worksheet. The reason is that  Model Name could have one or two controllers. I have created all the queries, Power Pivots, and relationships. The link to the file is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ekWolhdcM71gF8aD4kgn138RiXsetgxL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109177038280584739368&rtpof=true&sd=true) (this is all public data) if someone is willing to take a look and provide the guideline.

PROBLEM:
Due to Model Name's duplication under the "intel" worksheet, I have created a "DUP" column to identify duplicates in my data with the "X." I thought if I made a column “RELATED -Devide by 2” in the Power Pivot “Intel” with the formula `=IF([DUP]="X," [RELATED - 12 Month Volume]/2, [RELATED - 12 Month Volume])",` I would be able to show correct 12Month Volume based on Volume worksheet. This is partially true. I came to an understanding that I need to use both, “RELATED - 12 Month Volume” and “RELATED -Devide by 2” depending on what slicer I am filtering with

- If Filtered by FORM Factor or Vendor, I can use RELATED - Divide by 2 (Orange color as shown below).
- Now, if I filter above with Controller (like X710-TM4), this is not good. For Controller Filter, I would need to use “RELATED - 12 Month Volume” (Blue color as shown below), which is NOT suitable for above

How do I accomplish this? One set of slicers and be able to drill down and show correct value based on slicer used
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4kDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... I figured it out with the CROSSFILTER measure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).